# Jquery Interval Loop change numbers after every one min?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a function for change a div number when one min is passed. I need to do this again and again. I mean to say if i give numbers 241. I need to change this after one min 320 or like this any one. I try to much but still not success full. If any one knows how to do this please help me.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot 
but how do i change numbers with my function in div

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some codes... You just need to use setInteval.

Comment: Change content: `$('#id').text(320)`

Comment: Just a heads-up for the future - http://api.jquery.com/, or google "jquery set text in div"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval` for that.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('nums');
var currNum = 260;
div.innerHTML = 260;

setInterval(function () {
  currNum += 20;
  div.innerHTML = currNum;
}, 2000); // time in miliseconds.
```

```html
<div id="nums"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML = Date();
    }, 5000);
</script>
<body>
    <div id="divid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ $("#id").html(320); }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function

```js
$(() => {
  var counter = 0;
  window.setInterval(() => {
    counter++;
    $("#test").html('Has been running since '+counter+' seconds!');

  }, 1000); // After 1s for demo
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```